# In a shell (bash) How can I execute more than one command in a pipeline?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, pipeline

I'm trying pipe the output of an awk command through more than one command at once in a Bash shell, following my knowledge I'm coming up with this:

```
awk '$13 ~ /type/ {print $15}' filename.txt | (wc -l || sort -u)
```

I want the result of the awk command to be both counted AND sorted, how can I accomplish that?
Even with && command it doesn't work, it does execute the first command and then exits.
I guess it is my knowledge of bash which is failing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to send output to two different commands in a single line, you'll need to do process substituion.

Try this:

```
awk '$13 ~ /type/ {print $15}' filename.txt | tee >(wc -l >&2) | sort -u
```

This outputs the line count on stderr and the sorted output on stdout.  If you need the line count on stdout, you can do that leave off the `>&2`, but then it will be passed to the sort call and (most likely) sorted to the top of the output.

EDIT: corrected description of what happens based on further testing.

Comment: @Lex: if bash is invoked as `sh`, it will go into compatibility mode, and process substitution won't work.  explicitly call the shell as `bash` and it should be fine.

Comment: This works but it's not so neat:
awk '$13 ~ /type/ {print $15}' filename.txt | tee test.txt | sort -u ; cat test.txt | wc -l

Comment: Anyway voting this as accepted because it answers more precisely my question.

Comment: It works for me, but be aware that this is a bash-specific feature.  It will certainly not work on sh, or on bash-invoked-as-sh, and I don't know which other shells have it (e.g. ksh, zsh, etc.).  It also doesn't work with busybox's shell, which is used on many installers and embedded devices masquerading as bash.

Comment: @Walter: it works in ksh93, bash and zsh, but not in more basic shells such as pdksh, ash or busybox.

Answer (score 4):

in that case, do your counting in awk , why the need for pipes? don't make it more complicated

```
awk '$13 ~ /type/ {print $15;c++}END{print c} ' filename.txt | sort -u
```

Answer (score 1):

If the size in the output is not too large to fit in memory and you don't need the `wc` and `sort` commands to work in parallel for performance reasons, here's a relatively simple solution:

```
output=$(awk '$13 ~ /type/ {print $15}' filename.txt; echo a)
printf "%s" "${output%a}" | sort -u
printf "%s" "${output%a}" | wc -l
```

That complication with the the extra `a` is in case the `awk` command might print some empty lines at the end of the input, which the `$()` construct would strip. You can easily choose which of `sort` or `wc` should appear first.

---

Here's a way that works with any POSIX shell (ash, bash, ksh, zsh, ...) but only on systems that have `/dev/fd` (which includes reasonably recent Linux, *BSD and Solaris). Like [Walter's similar construction using the simpler method available in bash, ksh93 and zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398068/in-a-shell-bash-how-can-i-execute-more-than-one-command-in-a-pipeline/3398126#3398126), the output of `wc` and the output of `sort` may be intermixed.

```
{
  awk '$13 ~ /type/ {print $15}' filename.txt |
  tee /dev/fd3 |
  wc -l
} 3>&1 1>&3 | sort -u
```

---

If you both need to deal with intermediate output that doesn't comfortably fit in memory *and* don't want to have the output of the two commands intermixed, I don't think there's an easy way in a POSIX shell, though it should be doable with ksh or zsh coprocesses.

Answer (score 0):

I think the bigger question is: what are you expecting the output to be?

If you're trying to do two things, then do two things:

```
awk '$13 ~ /type/ {print $15}' filename.txt > tempfile
wc -l < tempfile
sort -u < tempfile
rm tempfile
```

Comment: I expect my output to be two  or more lines, one line with one result (a line count) and another (or more) with a sort of the results of the awk command.
I was wondering if it was possible to even do this on one line because I would have to repeat the awk command or assign its result to a variable instead.

Comment: See my edit to see how to do it without repeating awk. In general, even if you find a way to do what you are trying to do, don't do it. You should never intentionally write confusing code.

Comment: I didn't find it confusing, I just thought it was more efficient doing it this way.

Comment: But you did have to ask on StackOverflow.com how to do it. Clarity is always superior to obscurity.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't realize that, you're right, next time I will for sure. :)

Comment: 'cat tempfile > sort -u' is equivalent to 'cat tempfile -u > sort'.  You probably meant to use '|', in which case you have UUOC.  Just do 'sort -u < tempfile'.

Comment: @William Pursell: Both good points. Edited answer as suggested.

Comment: @Stargazer712: there's no reason to use a temporary file unless the output it too big to fit in memory, that's what `$(...)` is for. Also creating a temporary file is a nontrivial problem: what if the current directory is not writable? What if two instances of the script are running in parallel? etc.

Comment: @Giles: In that case, I would write a custom script or program to perform the actions he is attempting to perform. Millions of man hours are wasted every year trying to decipher confusing code. Clarity is **always** superior to obscurity.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use named pipes created with mkfifo in combination with tee. An example is at http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/tee.shtml